# How can i fetch featured products in magento for each category on home page?

Tags: php, magento

I created a new attribute using admin panel. from each category i set 2-6 products as featured. on home page i can get all the featured products using this code:

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$catalog = $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setStoreId($storeId);
// get all products that are marked as featured
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->limit(6);
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('featured_product');
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
array('attribute' => 'featured', 'eq' => true),
));
```

Now I have few categories Men, Women, Kids. Each category have sub categories.

Now my question is how can I re-arrange my collection code so that i can get featured products of Men, then featured products of Women and then featured products of Kids?